# How to fix bcd error

Tags: windows-7, window

Window failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
1. Insert your window installation disc and restart your computer.
2.choose your language,and then click next.
3.click repair your computer.
If you don't have this docs , contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.
Status: 0xc000000f
Info : the boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.

Comment: https://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-fix-error-0xc000000f-the-boot-selection-failed-because-a-required-device-is-inaccessible ; https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-update/0xc000000f-the-boot-selection-failed-because-a/941a723d-48fc-4357-b92f-a16dfec90562

Answer (score 0):

[It is a Issue with the Hard Disk.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-update/0xc000000f-the-boot-selection-failed-because-a/941a723d-48fc-4357-b92f-a16dfec90562?auth=1)

Try the link above to solve the Problem if it doesn't work or its difficult then try the HBCD iso. Make a usb bootable and boot into it and then use the windows xp mini in it, It has many tools within it for troubleshooting and whatnot, but be carefull with those tools. I would recommend to first check if your Hard Disk is Healthy or not by using HD Tune and Victoria (Names of the Tools) and then move forward with Recovery or Repairing.
There is also the Easy Recovery Essentials by NeoSmart Tech.It is Paid but it is very Good in Solving all these kinds of Issues. Cheers and All the Best!